# How to use the Message headers of camel apns component?

Tags: apache-camel

Can someone please provide me with an example on how to use Message headers,CamelApnsTokens and CamelApnsMessageType of camel apns component.
I am new to camel and i went through the apns component webpage on camel website but was not able to make much out of it as it provides the route definitions only.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set CamelApnsTokens and CamelApnsMessageType just like this

```
from("direct:test")
   .setHeader("CamelApnsTokens",constant("TOKEN"))
   .setHeader("CamelApnsMessageType",constant("STRING"))
   .to("apns:notify");
```

Comment: Hi..many thanks for your help.However,i have couple of more doubts.What does 'constant' means here and how to get the list of inactive devices after we have consumed feedback from the "apns:consumer" to "mock:result".